# Use a WHERE clause that's stored in a table?

Tags: javascript, sql-injection

**Background:**

I have a [workorder management system](https://www.ibm.com/ca-en/marketplace/maximo) (WMS).

- The WMS has functionality that allows users to [save queries](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSPJLC_7.6.0/com.ibm.si.mpl.doc/configure/t_create_query_prv_app.html).
- The queries are saved in a database table called `QUERY` (in a `CLAUSE` column).

An example of a value in the `CLAUSE` column would be:

`((woclass = 'WORKORDER' or woclass = 'ACTIVITY') and contains(description,'$paint') > 0  and historyflag = 0 and istask = 0 and siteid = 'SERVICES')`

---

**Scenario:**

I'm trying to learn how to properly integrate the WMS system with a separate [GIS system](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/administer/windows/what-is-portal-for-arcgis-.htm) (both systems are broswer-based/Oracle/internal systems).

I would like to utilize the saved WMS queries by integrating them into the GIS system's web map. I'll write a GIS web map widget (JavaScript) that would allow users to choose and execute queries from the `QUERY` table.

- *From a drop-down menu, choose a WHERE clause name from the `QUERY` table, extract the value from the `CLAUSE` column, and use it in a customized [filtering tool](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-filter.htm) (to query a GIS table).*

**Question:**

Would the above-mentioned GIS widget be vulnerable to injection? If so, what can I do to make it safe?

---

*I'm new to the IT industry and am  trying to learn how to **safely** integrate/share queries between systems. Layman's terms would be appreciated.*

Answer (score 1):

No, your system doesn't *need* to have an injection vulnerability.

While you could implement these clauses easily (and insecurely) by doing an "eval", or tossing the result in a WHERE with no validation, it is possible to do that properly. You would parse the to verify it conforms to the proper format, and then build back a now-trusted query.

Comment: Thanks. Are there standard methods for *parsing, verifying, and re-assembling* complex WHERE clauses that I could use? Or do I need to write this from scratch?

Comment: It will depend on how complex you want to go. For a simple one a regex would be enough, such as `^wo(class|order) ([!<>]?=|NOT )?LIKE) '([^']|\\')+' ((and|or) wo(class|order) ([!<>]?=|NOT )?LIKE)  '([^']|\\')+')*$` Complex queries will probably need an actual parser (such as one build with lex/yacc or the result or an ABNF grammer). Basically, you will want to forbid anything that would be allowed by the underlying SQL parser in the resulting, but that should not be allowed by the user, so you do that by making a parser that can validate that the input conforms to what **is* allowed.